# Oracle SQL Exclude row from query results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables in Oracle SQL:

PROJECT (**PID**, Pname, Budget, *DID*)

DIVISION (**DID**, Dname)

**Bold** = Primary key

*Italic* = Foreign key

I want to list the division that has more projects than the division marketing.

Here is my code:

```
select dname as "Division"
from division d, project p
where d.did = p.did
group by dname
having count(pid) >= all
(select count(p.pid)
from project p, division d
where p.did = d.did and d.dname = 'marketing')
```

I return the correct record but also the marketing record. How can I exclude the marketing record from the results?

Comment: I figured it out:

    select dname as "Division"
    from division d, project p
    where d.did = p.did and dname <> 'marketing'
    group by dname
    having count(pid) >= all
    (select count(p.pid)
    from project p, division d
    where p.did = d.did and d.dname = 'marketing')

Comment: Or how about `count(pid) > all` so you do not include departments that have the same number of projects as marketing (including itself!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you exclude the marketing record from your initial SQL by adding:

```
and d.dname != 'marketing'
```

To the first `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You might gain efficiency with a common table expression (WITH clause) to aggregate the count by department, then you can query it ...

```
with cte as (
  select   dname,
           count(*) projects
  from     project p,
           division d
  where    p.did = d.did
  group by dname)
select dname,
       projects
from   cte
where  projects > (select projects
                  from   cte
                  where  dname = 'Marketing)
```